# Start async operations, then await later

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm just now starting to play with async and await.  I have 8 separate db calls, some dependent on others.  I'd like to be able to kick off 3 async methods, then when a certain 1 returns, kick off 3 others, then when a certain 1 returns from that, kick off 2 more.  I am currently using 3 Parallel.Invoke methods to accomplish this, but each parallel has to wait until **ALL methods** return.  I only care about **1 method** returning, the others can run in the background until an `await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3,...,t6)` at the end.  **Is there a way to pull this off with async/await?**

I understand that await isn't blocking, but it is stopping execution of my main method (w/the 8 db calls) until the value returns from the method (just like a synchronous method does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAny` to wait for any one of several tasks:

```
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2, t3, ...);
```

If you have a more complex dependency structure, then I recommend representing that with `async` methods as such:

```
static async Task DoMasterOperationAsync()
{
  var result = await StartSomething();
  await Task.WhenAll(DoComplexOperationAsync(), result.NextT1Async());
}

static async Task DoComplexOperationAsync()
{
  var result1 = await T1Async();
  await Task.WhenAll(result1.NextT1Async(), result1.NextT2Async(), result1.NextT3Async());
}

await Task.WhenAll(DoMasterOperationAsync(), t2, t3, ...);
```

Comment: The functionality I was looking for can be achieved this way.  After your comment, I read in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177.aspx) that Task.Run is specifically for Compute bound tasks.  I'm marking this as the answer, but could you tell me why this is better than Task.Run?  Assuming I don't care that I'm using up the threads for the duration of the calls, does it matter?  This solution forces me to create intermediate POCOs for moving data around and is less clear to me.

Comment: `Task.Run` will create a new `Task` that must execute on the thread pool. In this case, it just has more overhead. Additional POCO instances are cheap compared to additional thread pool tasks.

Comment: Additionally, you can create a `var parallelOperations = new List<Task>();`, then add tasks you want to await later, e.g.  `parallelOperations.Add(context.InsertAsync(pocoObj));` and finally do a `if (parallelOperations.Any())
                    {
                        await Task.WhenAll(parallelOperations);
                    }` - This makes especially sense if you have more than a handfull of tasks to await.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I didn't know about `Task.Run` that allows you to kick off a task, then await it later.  I found this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966007/186483) by @StephenCleary.  Thanks Stephen, you've got my upvote there!  Here's my completely contrived example that accomplishes what I set out to do above:

```
        Func<Task<int>> t1 = async () => { await Task.Delay(4000); return 1; };
        Func<Task<int>> t2 = async () => { await Task.Delay(5000); return 2; };
        Func<int, Task<int>> t3 = async (val) => { await Task.Delay(3000); return 3; };
        Func<int, Task<int>> t4 = async (val) => { await Task.Delay(4000); return 4; };
        Func<int, Task<int>> t5 = async (val) => { await Task.Delay(3000); return 5; };
        Func<int, Task<int>> t6 = async (val) => { await Task.Delay(2000); return 6; };
        Func<int, Task<int>> tSecondary = async (val) => { await Task.Delay(3000); return 7; };
        Func<Task<int>> tPrimary = async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); return 8; };
        //kick off first 3 calls
        var primaryR = Task.Run(tPrimary);
        var t1R = Task.Run(t1);
        var t2R = Task.Run(t2);
        //await 1 of the 3
        var primary = await primaryR;
        //start 2 of 3 dependent tasks
        var t3R = Task.Run(() => t3(primary));
        var t4R = Task.Run(() => t4(primary));
        //kick off and await secondaryMasterTaskAsync
        var secondary = await tSecondary(primary);
        //start final 2
        var t5R = Task.Run(() => t5(secondary));
        var t6R = Task.Run(() => t6(secondary));
        //await all tasks that haven't been awaited previously
        var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(t1R, t2R, t3R, t4R, t5R, t6R);
```

Comment: You should only use `Task.Run` to free up the UI thread when you have CPU-intensive work to do. In this case, since your operations are all I/O-bound (db calls), you should not use `Task.Run`. Rather, split up the calls logically into `async` methods as I describe in my answer.